# Join SQL tables, but with additional info from joined table

Tags: sql, join

Here is a basic illustration of the issue

I have two tables I want to join. 
One table contains information about a product sale. (product_sales)
The other contains keys for the names of locations. (states_keys)

Both contain the same column 'state_key'.
The states_keys table has an additional column called 'state_names'.

I would like to join the table so that I can view the accurate state name that coordinates to each product sale.

So, I want to join where each table's state_key are = but display the additional column state_names from table states_keys.

Comment: Read here [How ask a good sql question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557)

Comment: Every basic sql tutorial covers that.

Comment: What database you are using? A simple join of product _sales and states_keys would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_sales.*, state_names
FROM product_sales
INNER JOIN states_keys
ON product_sales.state_key = states_keys.state_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
Select prod.*, state.state_names
from product_sales prod
inner join states_keys state on state.state_key = prod.state_key
```